# Only @2x sized images for iPhone5?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to trim some size off of my binary, and I remembered I have some backgrounds that are only used on the iPhone5. I noticed for these backgrounds I included the @1x and @2x sizes, but was wondering, since it'll only be used for the iPhone5, do I even have to bother with the @1x sized images? It seems to me they wouldn't be needed, but just wanted to verify.

Comment: Yes, images that are only used on retina devices only need to be in the @2x format. No "@1x" version is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're displaying in `UIImageView` or similar then you technically never need include @1xs, as images that are too large will be scaled down. That's not what people do in practice since it would multiply the memory footprint for graphics by four on the older devices but if you're confident that a particular graphic is used only on the retina devices then you can definitely safely include it, with or without the @2x file name suffix, and with no alternative.

(aside: as per rmaddy's comment below, the net effect of whether you include @2x or not in this case will be whether the resulting UIImage obtains an appropriate `scale`; it's always 1.0 unless there's an @2x suffix in which case it's 2.0)

Comment: I don't literally include @1x in my file extension, I was just referring it to that way to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think there is a typo the last sentence of your answer. The retina image should have the @2x part in the name and the non-retina image isn't needed.

Comment: @maddy Oh, no, it's just [very] poorly written. What I meant was that if you're not differentiating between 1x and 2x then why even include the 2x suffix?

Comment: @Tommy Because the UIImage methods use the `@2x` to set the image's scale properly. Retina images should have the `@2x` part in the name. BTW - it's `rmaddy`, not `maddy`.

Comment: @rmaddy I was obviously fooled by maddysoft.com; apologies. I've also updated my answer per the observation that `scale` is cribbed from the suffix.